# Obtener datos en php enviados por post con fetch en react native

Tags: php, react-native, post, fetch

llevo días tratando de resolver el problema he visto gran cantidad de ejemplos pero sigue se funcionar:

Estoy desarrollando una APP en React Native y en el inicio de sesión envío el usuario y clave que el usuario inserta pero al recibir los datos en php para realizar las comprobaciones nunca llegan los datos enviados.

Mi código js

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues(),
    validationSchema: validacionesFormularioIniciarSesion(),
    validateOnChange: false,
    onSubmit: async (fromValue) => {
        setLoading(true);
        console.log("Formulario enviado");
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('var_user', '5658451554132');
        formData.append('var_pasw', '5658451554132');
        
        fetch("MI_URL_API", {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'x-api-key': '364332437e8474839343854548574874',
                'User-Agent' : 'My-App',
            }),
            body: formData,
        })
        .then( (response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(json);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    },
});
```

Código PHP para recibir los datos

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-api-key, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Content-type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");
header("Allow: POST, GET");
$datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$result = array('code' => "1", 'var_user' => $datos["var_user"], 'var_pasw' => $datos["var_pasw"]);
echo json_encode($result);
```

?>

Respuesta del php, que las variables están vacías

```
Object {"code": "1", "var_pasw": null, "var_user": null}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormData es un objeto que se envía con pares de `variable = valor`, por lo que solo debes tomar los datos desde `$_POST`:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-api-key, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
// Encabezado de contenido de acuerdo a lo que se va a devolver
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
// Permite solo el método POST para evitar errores
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Allow: POST");
$result = [
    'code' => "1",
    'var_user' => $_POST["var_user"],
    'var_pasw' => $_POST["var_pasw"]
];
echo json_encode($result);
```

Si solo estás recibiendo datos, no tiene sentido agregar el encabezado con tipo de contenido `multipart/form-data`, que también está sobrando en la petición AJAX:

```
    fetch("MI_URL_API", {
        method: 'POST',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            // Fetch elegirá el tipo de contenido (Content-Type)
            'x-api-key': '364332437e8474839343854548574874',
            'User-Agent' : 'My-App',
        }),
        body: formData,
    })
```

De hecho, puedes omitir el encabezado con tipo de contenido ([referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)):

> Tanto peticiones y respuestas (y por extensión la function fetch()), intentarán inteligentemente determinar el tipo de contenido. Una petición también establecerá automáticamente la propiedad Context-Type de la cabecera si no es ha establecido una.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, esto soluciono mi problema

Answer (score 0):

en el php que te recibe los datos pone esto para testear que te llega antes de alterar el dato

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input",true);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Muestra el siguiente error  JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "string"